# How Do I Create Semesters or Departments with the Valence API?

Tags: desire2learn

I am wanting to create an integration between an SIS system and D2L using the Valence API. When new semesters or departments are created in the SIS, I want to create them automatically in D2L so that course templates and course offerings can be created in real time as they are created in the SIS.

I am not able to find the routing to use to create org units in the API reference documentation. It looks like all I can do is rearrange the org unit structure or create new org unit types; however, that is not what I wish to accomplish. Is it even possible to create org units using the Valence API? If so, what routing do I use?

On a side note, if it isn't possible to create org units using the Valence API, what would be a usage scenario for creating org unit types through the API? The org unit types seem to be a one time setup to me, and not something generally automated in any fashion.

Answer (score 1):

While at the time this question was asked, the Valence Learning Framework API did not provide API calls to alter the org structure "above" the course offering level (that is: calls did exist to add/remove/modify course offerings, sections, and groups, but not calls to add/remove/modify departments, semesters, or custom org units), at this point (as of D2L's Learning Suite v10.2.0) routes do exist to manipulate the org structure via the API.

The API now provides routes to create custom org units, and modify the assigned parents and children for org units, so that you can now effectively insert new org units into the existing organizational structure. These routes were added in the LP product component's version 1.3 API (delivered in Learning Suite 10.2.0).

Additionally, in the LP v1.4 API (delivered in Learning Suite 10.3.0), API routes were added to directly modify some of the properties for an existing, single org unit, to retrieve lists org unit properties (and filter on the list), and to find leaf-node and detached org units (those without children and those without parents).

All these routes were added to make it easier for client admin teams to write off-board scripts and services intended to assist in managing the org structure, as with your described use-case here.